# Android Linear Layout inside ScrollView does not keep scrolling while dynamically add view to it

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I has a Linear Layout inside a Scroll View.
And new Views are dynamically added the Linear Layout when the layout is scrolled to nearly bottom(200 pixel near bottom).

If I scroll slow, it works great.

If I scroll fast, it scrolls down to old bottom(the bottom view before add news views) + some Y offset, and bounce back to old bottom, without continue scrolling down; just like a overscroll effect.

What I want is when it is scrolled to nearly bottom, it will add new views, and continue scrolling down until scroll speed down and stop.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Post some code.  Any thoughts on using a listview? https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless  should help